# How to display a text as marker name in RVIZ in Python

Tags: ros, python, rviz, marker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to display a text as marker name in RVIZ in Python:
I want to add names for the markers in rviz. Can anyone tell me how to add it in python.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/100846/how-to-display-a-text-as-marker-name-in-rviz-in-python/) by [Rikardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/5410/rikardo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2013-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/73051/using-makers-array-in-rviz/?answer=73726#post-id-73726) has all the info (and link to the right tutorial) you need.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on 2021-01-25**:
displaying text fails